# Laravel Eloquent - Model::all() method give all result including soft deletes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, soft-delete

When I select all records using eloquent **Model::all()** method it's give me soft delete record too.

Model class

```
protected $table = 'tr_fl_tax_charges';

protected $primaryKey = 'fl_tax_id';

use SoftDeletes;

protected $softDelete = true;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Controller class

**Case 1**

```
public function index()
{

    $tax = Tax::all();

    return $tax;
}
```

it's give me all record including soft deleted row.

**Case 2**

```
public function index()
{

    $tax = Tax::all()->where('deleted_at' , '=', null);

    return $tax;
}
```

this case give me correct output and not including soft deleted rows but it's give me all the columns and I don't need all columns.I need only 4 columns.

**Case 3**

If I add column name that need in **all()** method it's give me soft deleted row too.

```
public function index()
{

    $tax = Tax::all('fl_tax_id','fl_tax_type','fl_tax_name','fl_charge_type','fl_charge_rate')->where('deleted_at' , '=', null);

    return $tax;
}
```

**Case 4**

If I add one more column deleted_At in case 3 it's give me expected output.

```
public function index()
{

    $tax = Tax::all('fl_tax_id','fl_tax_type','fl_tax_name','fl_charge_type','fl_charge_rate', 'deleted_at')->where('deleted_at' , '=', null);

    return $tax;
}
```

What I want is I want only those record which is not soft deleted and from those records I want to select columns. How ?

**UPDATE WITH MODEL AND CONTROLLER FILES**

Tax.php (Model) - here BaseModel extends Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Tax extends BaseModel

{

protected $table = 'tr_fl_tax_charges';

protected $primaryKey = 'fl_tax_id';

use SoftDeletes;

protected $softDelete = true;

//protected $fillable = ['fl_tax_type' , 'fl_tax_name' , 'fl_charge_type' , 'fl_charge_rate'];

protected $guarded = [];

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


}
```

TaxController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Tax;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class TaxController extends Controller

{

public function index()

{

$tax = Tax::all();

return $tax;

}
```

Comment: why can't you try with get() instead of all()

Comment: get() is working perfect. but Model::all() can't give all record that is not soft deleted ?

Comment: you can get same with get(), is there any particular reason why you don't want to use get()?

Comment: did you use trait `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` in your model?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal yes I have added softDeletes trait in model class

Comment: Can you show your `BaseModel`?

Comment: @patricus BaseModel is empty class which extends Model.

Comment: Are you overriding the `boot` method in your `Tax` model?

Comment: @patricus no. not at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `protected $softDelete = true;` only leave the `use SoftDeletes;` will be OK.

Comment: I tried to remove protected $softDelete = true; but not working.

Comment: Can you show your migration code of this table, and the `desc tablename` here.

Answer (score 1):

With the current information provided, there is no reason that Case 1 should fail. Soft deletes work with the `all()` method, and I don't see any other issues in the currently provided code that would change that. I will update this answer if more code is provided that reveals the issue.

Case 2 "works" because you're actually calling `where()` on the `Collection` of all your `Tax` records. `Tax::all()` queries the database and builds a `Collection` of all the results, and then you're using `where()` to filter out the results with a null `deleted_at` field. This is highly inefficient.

Case 3 fails because your select list doesn't contain the `deleted_at` field. So, when you call `where()` on the `Collection` to only see the records where `delete_at` is null, all records will match since `deleted_at` doesn't exist. This is still calling `where()` on the `Collection`, not adding a where clause to the query, so it is inefficient.

Case 4 "works" again because you added the `deleted_at` field back in, so it will be in the `Collection` results, and the filtering can filter out the records where `deleted_at` is not null. But again, this is filtering the `Collection` of all your Tax records PHP side, not adding a where condition to your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

Change your `Tax` model and try:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Tax extends BaseModel

{
use SoftDeletes;

protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

protected $table = 'tr_fl_tax_charges';


protected $guarded = ['fl_tax_id','_token'];


}
```